# Use Page Items in a Button Link in Apex Express

Tags: button, hyperlink, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i have a little problem. I'm using Oracle Applicarion Express and i'm trying to use some page items in a Link created for a button. I created the Button as region button, and selected in the region" Action when button clicked" "Redirect to URL". In this URL i want to use two pageitems. I tried already to use them mit ":PAGE_ITEM" or "&PAGE_ITEM." but non way works. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What does the resulting hyperlink look like? The chance is great that it looks like

```
f?p=<app_id>:10:<session id>::::P10_ITEM1,P10_ITEM2:,
```

This is because when using the substitution syntax like `&PAGE_ITEM.` will put the session state of the referenced item in the string. Since the button is rendered during the loading of the page it will use the session state of the item at that time.
When you then fill in a value for `PAGE_ITEM`, this will not change the session state of that item - and even if it did it would not matter since the button was already rendered.
If this is the case then you'd better have the button submit the page, and define an on submit before validations/computations branch to act on that button. In the branch you can then safely use the session state of the required items.

Comment: Hey Tom, APEX didn't substitute anything in the string, but i found my mistake. I used a "Region Button". Now i use a "pageitem Button" and it works!